# Hwioauth failure login referer path

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

In hwi_oauth I can set param with path to failure redirect. I want to redirect to referer. Can I set it in hwi or must create `failure_handler` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `failure_handler` is required.

for example:

```
<?php

class OAuthFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface {

    public function onAuthenticationFailure( Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {

        if ( !$exception instanceof AccountNotLinkedException ) {
            throw $exception;
        }
}
```